# Unity.Mvc3 vs Unity.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

Using the Unity.Mvc3 with a Mvc 3 application, i could register my `IDummyService` as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<IDummyService, DummyService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

On each web request, a new instance of my `IDummyService` is created (as explained in this [article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-the-unity.mvc3-nuget-package-to-reconcile-mvc3-unity-and-idisposable)), but since I upgraded Mvc 3 to Mvc 4 and hense Unity.Mvc3 to Unity.Mvc, an single instance is created and used across all web requests, untill restarting the app. Basically, `IDummyService` is a singleton in a Mvc 4 application when using `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`. For me this is hard to believe this is intended new behavior in Unity.Mvc.

Is there a better explanations for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Unity.Mvc3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc3/) and [Unity.Mvc](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) are created by two different organizations and have different implementations.

Unity.Mvc3 creates a child container per web request.  This works well with the built-in `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.

Unity.Mvc does not create a child container, but instead chose to create a new LifetimeManager called `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.